# Is using floats and comparison as error code portable?

Tags: c, floating-point, comparison, portability

I plan to use special floats values to return error codes from a function, such as `99.75f` which is representable in IEEE-754:

```
float myFunction(void)
{
    /* Do some stuff */
    if(error) return 99.75f;
}
```

and later to check the value like this:

```
float result = myFunction();
if(result == 99.75f) printf("Error !");
```

Assuming my compilers conform to C90 or C99 standards, is this solution portable ? Will it works on any platform ?
Or is the compiler allowed to do some magic or some optimizations that would cast the float in a double, change its representation, etc., what which could break the equality check?

The famous [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) does not seem to cover this case (C-specific).
Doing a comparison with FLT_EPSILON or ULPs would be irrelevant as I definitively want to check the representation of the float...

Comment: Portable? Maybe (if you only care about implementations that use IEEE-754). Good practice? Absolutely not. The other option is to return the error indication separately, i.e. `float myFunction(int *error)` or `int myFunction(float *result)`

Comment: @user3386109 Could you elaborate on the bad practice aspect in an answer? (Note that the CPython source does something [very similar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba518804bf4c1ea01df5e622b333d3116cbaa3bd/Objects/longobject.c#L2883-L2887).)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Then perhaps you should be the one posting an answer stating that CPython is an example of good practice.

Comment: @user3386109: Yes, it is terrible practice, just like using `int` return codes from functions to sometimes return a value (number of bytes transferred, stream number, number of arguments converted) and sometimes to return an error indication (resource not available, EOF) or using a pointer to represent either an address or the lack of an address (`NULL`).

Comment: All I have to do is wait, because maintenance happens. Someone who doesn't understand all of the nuances of floating point numbers touches that code, and the whole thing blows up. That's what makes it bad practice. Unlike say returning `NULL`. With `NULL`, you don't need a wall of text to explain why you're absolutely certain that you might be fairly safe.

Comment: @user3386109: Yes, no bugs ever happened with null pointers. Everybody understands arithmetic with pointers, including the finer details of which additions and subtractions are allowed, and which conversions have defined results.

Comment: Where NaN support exists, a typical error return is `if(error) return NAN;`

Comment: @user3386109 According to the accepted answer I understand that using floats as error code is as safe as using int, but I would consider it as a bad practice because it mixes two concepts, two meanings, (error code and return values) in a single variables, rather than just because they are floats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard does not guarantee much about floating-point behavior. It does say:

> All floating constants of the same source form shall convert to the same internal format with the same value.

This means that `99.75f` will produce the same value, whatever that may be, wherever it appears in your program. It does not guarantee that `99.750f` will convert to the same value, so you would have to be sure to use exactly the same source text each time it appears. Neither does it guarantee that other source text, such as `99.76f`, will not convert to the same value. So you will want to ensure that the special value you use is well separated from any values that will arise in calculation.

The C standard does not guarantee that the base of the floating-point system is either 2 or 10. So, relying on the standard alone, you cannot be sure that 99.75 is representable. Of course, you are unlikely to encounter an implementation that uses base 3.

The C standard allows implementations to evaluate expressions with extra range and precision. However, once `99.75f` is converted to floating-point, merely giving it extra range and precision would not alter it. Operations such as `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, and library routines could produce approximate results, but, presumably, you are not operating on this value.

The C standard seems to imply that only one base will be used for the floating-point types, at least for the normal ones, as it defines only `FLT_RADIX` to report the base used for the floating-point system but defines `FLT_MANT_DIG` and `DBL_MANT_DIG` to report the number of digits used in the significands of `float` and `double`. So you do not have to worry that 99.75 would change when converted from `float` to `double` or extended precisions. It should only be represented with more digits in the same base, not converted to a new base, and hence the extra digits would be zero. (Of course, narrowing conversions could change it, so you would want to define the special value in terms of `float`, so that it can only get wider.)

Overall, I expect you are fairly safe in this. However, it is not necessarily good design. Certainly the special value ought to be specified only once in the source text, by using a preprocessor macro or an identifier defined to be a constant value.

Comment: "....guarantee that the base..." Here I thought `FLT_RADIX` must 10 or a power of 2.  Yet cannot find this supported in C, just `FLT_RADIX > 1`.  LSNED.

Comment: @chux: 16 is another possibility. I think the Xerox Sigma 9 used 16, but that is a vague memory, so it could be wrong.

Comment: Some old systems I've studied use  16, [a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917087/is-using-floats-and-comparison-as-error-code-portable/48917284?noredirect=1#comment84844135_48917284), like IBM/370 or 10: GP L3055.  Uncommon these days.